# Con openpyxl no puedo guardar el libro con workbook.save("archivo")

Tags: openpyxl

```
 

       import openpyxl as opx          # openpyxl versión 3.0.2
        from openpyxl import Workbook
        workbook = opx.load_workbook('f:/IA/test.xlsx') # Carga bien y puedo añadir hojas, cambiar valores, etc.
    
        workbook.save('test2.xlsx')   # PERO A CONTINUACIÓN NO PUEDO GUARDARLO
```

No guarda el libro, siempre me da error. Toda la información que encuentro lo guarda con esta instrucción.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-2031d322fe01> in <module>
      6 # PERO A CONTINUACIÓN NO PUEDO GUARDARLO
      7 
----> 8 workbook.save('test2.xlsx')
```

c:\users\blanco\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py in save(self, filename)

```
    406         if self.write_only and not self.worksheets:
    407             self.create_sheet()
--> 408         save_workbook(self, filename)
    409 
    410
```

c:\users\blanco\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py in save_workbook(workbook, filename)

```
    291     archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
    292     writer = ExcelWriter(workbook, archive)
--> 293     writer.save()
    294     return True
    295
```

c:\users\blanco\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py in save(self)

```
    273     def save(self):
    274         """Write data into the archive."""
--> 275         self.write_data()
    276         self._archive.close()
    277
```

c:\users\blanco\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py in write_data(self)

```
    73             archive.writestr(ARC_THEME, theme_xml)
     74 
---> 75         self._write_worksheets()
     76         self._write_chartsheets()
     77         self._write_images()
```

c:\users\blanco\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py in _write_worksheets(self)

```
    213 
    214             ws._id = idx
--> 215             self.write_worksheet(ws)
    216 
    217             if ws._drawing:
```

c:\users\blanco\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py in write_worksheet(self, ws)

```
    198         else:
    199             writer = WorksheetWriter(ws)
--> 200             writer.write()
    201 
    202         ws._rels = writer._rels
```

c:\users\blanco\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet_writer.py in write(self)

```
    352         High level
    353         """
--> 354         self.write_top()
    355         self.write_rows()
    356         self.write_tail()
```

c:\users\blanco\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet_writer.py in write_top(self)

```
    96         cols
     97         """
---> 98         self.write_properties()
     99         self.write_dimensions()
    100         self.write_views()
```

c:\users\blanco\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet_writer.py in write_properties(self)

```
     58     def write_properties(self):
     59         props = self.ws.sheet_properties
---> 60         self.xf.send(props.to_tree())
     61 
     62
```

c:\users\blanco\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet_writer.py in get_stream(self)

```
    292                             continue
    293                         else:
--> 294                             xf.write(el)
    295                 except GeneratorExit:
    296                     pass
```

src\lxml\serializer.pxi in lxml.etree._IncrementalFileWriter.write()

TypeError: got invalid input value of type <class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'>, expected string or Element

Dice que espera un string, pero ya tiene un string

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo encontré.
Tenía instalada la versión 3.0.2, pero había dos versiones antiguas 1.0.x que interferían.
Desinstalé todo openpyxl y volví a instalar desde cero la 3.0.2
Y ya funciona.